# Fetch records from multiple tables at once in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

When I do something like the following, Rails queries the DB twice:

```
p = Post.find(1)
c = p.comments
```

The queries look like:

```
SELECT "posts".* from "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1

SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 1
```

Is there a way to combine them into 1 query? Something like:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*
FROM comments c
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1
) p ON p.id = c.post_id
```

And then have Rails split it into 2 types of records?

Comment: Yes. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby on Rails allows to [eager loading associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to avoid too many database queries – usually, this is used to reduce the common N+1 query problem to just two queries. For example, the following query would make only *two* queries even to load all posts and comments and it builds the associations internally.

```
Post.includes(:comments)
```

But *no* there is no way to automatically reduce a query like the one in your question to just *one query and* deconstruct the query result internally into different objects again.

When the deconstruction part is not important then you can write

```
Post.select('posts.*, comments.*').joins(:comments).where(id: 1)
```

Note that you might need to rename columns in the `select` call if there are columns having the same name in both tables.

Comment: When you intend to load the other table (like here), use `includes`. `joins` is for when you want to use other table's records for, say, filtering, but not load them. So, it should be `Post.includes(:comments).find(1)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sure, but `includes` usually generates two queries, but the OP was asking for just one. Therefore I was looking for a work-around that covers the OP's use-case. I added a sentence about `includes` and why it is the preferred way in Rails but doesn't solve the OPs requirements.

Comment: Ah, of course. Apologies, it's very early morning here.

Comment: No worries. @SergioTulentsev You help me to understand that I missed an important part in my answer. Happy New Year!

Comment: @spickermann  I am having NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' error when trying to do with includes.
Difference here is I am not taking it directly from model Post, I am using association here.
For eg: current_user.post.includes(:comments)
here I want post details and comments, it is getting op if we use two query.(N+1 issue)
for my case: current_user.organisation.includes(:projects),
current_user belongs to organisation, organisation has_many projects, project belongs to organisation. These are the associations. How can we do that?

Comment: @Ronats Your question ist quite different to the original question. I suggest opening a new question for that with a few more details.